# php for loop for date increment each time

Tags: php, date

I want to loop a date so that every time date is increment by previous date. my code is here. plz reply anyone, thanks in advance

```
  $today = date('Y-m-d'); 

  for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++){                
    $repeat = strtotime("+2 day",strtotime($today));
    echo $rdate = date('Y-m-d',$repeat);
  }
```

I want result as if today is 2016-04-04 than, 2016-04-06, 2016-04-08, 2016-04-10, 2016-04-12.

actually i want to make a reminder date where user enter reminder. lets a user want to add reminder today and want repeat it 5 time after 2days, 3days or what ever he wants, in next comming day. than how i repeat date with for loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

$today = date('Y-m-d'); 

for($i=1; $i<=4; $i++)
{
    $repeat = strtotime("+2 day",strtotime($today));
    $today = date('Y-m-d',$repeat);
    echo $today;
}
```

Output:

```
2016-04-06
2016-04-08
2016-04-10
2016-04-12
```

Comment: There is no need for an extra variable under `$today` :)

Comment: thanks, it works fine, i do mistake as an extra variable taken which is no need.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is what answer

> aslawin

The below example is to go through the date

```
  $begin = new DateTime($check_in);
  $end =  new DateTime($check_out);

  $step = DateInterval::createFromDateString('1 day');
  $period = new DatePeriod($begin, $step, $end);

  foreach ($period as $dt)
  {
      <sample code here>
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d'); 
for($i=1; $i<=8; $i++){
   if($i%2 == 0){
      $repeat = strtotime("+$i day",strtotime($today));
      echo $rdate = date('Y-m-d',$repeat);
   }  
}
```

**Result:**

```
2016-04-06
2016-04-08
2016-04-10
2016-04-12
```

In this example, you can use `$i%2 == 0` with `limit <= 8`

Comment: $i<=8 is a dynamic data so i cant us %. actually i want to make a reminder date where user enter reminder. lets a user want to add reminder today and want repeat it 5 time after 2days, 3days or what ever he wants, in next comming day.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop with base 2, then directly output your dates:

```
for( $i=2; $i<9; $i=$i+2 )
{
    echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime( "+ $i days" )) . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result:

```
2016-04-06
2016-04-08
2016-04-10
2016-04-12
```

Answer (score 0):

> actually i want to make a reminder date where user enter reminder.
>   lets a user want to add reminder today and want repeat it 5 time after
>   2days, 3days or what ever he wants, in next comming day. than how i
>   repeat date with for loop.

I'll help with the above. First of all I will just say I have a huge personal preference towards the `DateTime` object over simply using `date` it's more flexible and a hell of a lot more readable in my opinion, so when working with dates I would always suggest using that over `date()`

So here is some Code:

```
$date = new DateTime(); // Pretend this is what the User entered. We got it via $_POST or something.
$interval = 2; // Repeat x times at y day intervals. (Not including the initial)
$repeatAmount = 2; // Repeat the reminder x times

for ($i = 0; $i <= $repeatAmount; ++$i) {
    echo $date->format('d/m/Y');    
    $date->modify('+'. $interval .' day');
}
```

`$date = new DateTime()`Imagine this is the date the user entered, this is our starting point, our first reminder will at this time.

`$interval` and `$repeatAmount` are the interval in days, i.e. I want this to every 2 days and the amount of times you want it to repeat, in our example 2.

`for ($i = 0; $i <= $repeatAmount; ++$i) {` We want to loop as many times as the user says they want to repeat. Little note `++$i` tends to be a very minor performance boost over `$i++` in some scenarios, so it is usually better to default to that unless you specifically need to use `$i++`

`echo $date->format('d/m/Y');` Simply print out the date, i'll let you handle the reminder logic.

`$date->modify('+' . $interval . ' day');` Increment the `dateTime` object by the interval that the user has asked for, in our case increment by 2 days.

Any questions let me know.